# Em que tempos e pessoas podemos conjugar o verbo "convir", no sentido de "ser útil"?

Tags: tempo-verbal, verbos-defectivos

Estive tentando encontrar situações em que eu usaria **o verbo "convir", verbo transitivo indireto, no sentido de "ser útil"** e encontrei apenas...

- "Ah, este é o apartamento que nos convém."
- "Não vou aceitar porque não me convém."
- "Faça o que lhe convier."
- "Se te convier, aceite."
- "Se me conviesse eu aceitaria."

Sei tratar-se de um verbo defectivo, mas exatamente em que tempos e pessoas o verbo "convir" pode ser conjugado ?

Comment: Uff, é mesmo difícil responder a esta... Acho que se pode usar "estas soluções não me convêm", terceira pessoa do plural, e portanto não pode ser um verbo impessoal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não creio que se trate de um verbo defectivo. É verdade que *convir* no sentido de *ser útil, proveitoso, apropriado* [(aceções 1, 2 e 5 do Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/convir) é usado sobretudo na terceira pessoa: coisas ou combinações que convêm. Mas é possível formar frases perfeitamente inteligíveis com este significado de *convir* em todas as pessoas gramaticais. E só não encontrei para a segunda pessoa do plural (mas até isso o Artefacto encontrou, ver comentários; ênfase minha):

> Olha pra mim se te apraz,
>   E vê lá se te ***convenho***
>   Eu sou muito bom rapaz,
>   Só dinheiro é que eu não tenho.
>   [Maria Soares, *Os Três Santos Populares*](http://asminhascantigas.blogspot.pt/2013/10/os-tres-santos-populares.html)
>
> Alguém que saiba abrigar a minha inserviência, alguém que olhe para mim e que saiba que eu já não ***convenho*** a muita coisa, mas que continuo tendo valor.
>   [Diário do Rio Doce, 2-12-2013, p. 4](https://issuu.com/drdonline/docs/diario03122013)
>
> És tu que me ***convéns***,
>   Na tua singeleza
>   De barro popular, humano,
>   Pois me acenas com tudo o que preciso
>   [Paulo Quintela, “Santo Antoninho dos Pobres”, *Vértice*, Vol. XXVII, nº. 282-283, 1967, p.164-165, citado em Luís Machado de Abreu, “Santo António de Lisboa nos Caminhos da Europa”, *Revista Lusófona de Ciência das Religiões*, Ano XI, 2012, n. 16/17, p. 256.](http://recil.ulusofona.pt/bitstream/handle/10437/4267/Santo%20Ant%C3%B3nio%20de%20Lisboa%20nos%20caminhos%20da%20Europa.pdf?sequence=1)
>
> R140: Assumimos uma determinada postura em termos de valores, [...] e procuramos manter-nos isentos. Daí julgo eu, a nossa dificuldade em sobreviver! (Risos)
>   P141: (Risos)
>   R141: Temos sido sempre muito (Discurso imperceptível), porque não ***convimos*** a ninguém! Porque o poder político o que quer é ter pessoas coladas a si! (Risos)
>   [Entrevista a dirigente de ONG, repositório da Universidade de Lisboa](http://repositorio.ul.pt/bitstream/10451/4669/57/ulsd061541_td_anexo_8_12_Isabel.pdf)

Quanto aos tempos e modos não me parece haver dificuldades, exceto no caso do imperativo. Se olharmos para os exemplos acima, uma pessoa convém (a alguém) se tiver as qualidades desejadas (por esse alguém), e isso é um coisa que seria estranho, senão mesmo absurdo, pedir ou ordenar: «convém-me» ou «exijo que me convenhas».

Pensando bem, se uma pessoa, homem, mulher ou criança, pode convir (a alguém), então é possível conjugar o verbo em todas as pessoa gramaticais. E quem, pelo menos deste lado do Atlântico, é que não sabe [*que a mulher bonita é que me convém*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZCYrAlfU0E) com outra [versão um pouco diferente tocada aqui por uma tuna universitária](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jANGf3owG_w).

Comment: Se procurares por "convindes a" no Google Books encontras dois exemplos na 2a pessoa do plural, embora sejam com valor de singular.

Comment: @Artefacto Século XIX, não? Eu restringi a busca ao séc. XX para evitar a aceção *estar de acordo*, que era usado ao pontapé no séc. XIX. E como não vejo nenhuma diferença relevante aqui entre *és tu que me convéns* e *sois vós que me convindes*, não me preocupei muito com isso.

Comment: Sim, XIX. A primeira ocorrência é «Eil-o aqui: essa estimavel mulher, é ternamente adorada por um homem a quem estimo, a quem convém muito mais do que vós lhe convindes a ella: o vosso casamento desagrada-me, e prohibo-vos que trateis d'elle»

Answer (score 4):

No sentido de *ser conveniente/útil*, *convir* será geralmente conjugado apenas na terceira pessoal (verbo unipessoal), singular ou plural (refs. [1](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/verbos-unipessoais/) [2](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf56.php) [3](http://www.normaculta.com.br/classificacao-dos-verbos/)), com o singular o mais comum, até porque frequentemente o sujeito (com o qual o verbo concorda) assume a forma de oração (geralmente posposta ao verbo, como em *convinha que viessem mais cedo*).

Mas também se encontram com facilidade exemplos no plural (exemplos do CETEMPúblico):

> *par=ext183986-eco-94a-2*: Mas se o preço é o factor determinante na escolha, então os Continente [supermercado] são os que mais lhe **convêm**.
>   *par=ext69029-clt-95a-1*: No entanto, as aquisições dos americanos não **convêm** aos europeus, que terão, por sua vez, de negociar outro acordo; depois os próprios chineses se sentem pressionados, porque lhes exigem coisas a mais em tempo a menos.

No entanto, eu não excluiria completamente o uso de *convir* nas primeira e segunda pessoas. Se ***os Continente** me convêm* por que não *hás de **tu** convir-me*? Não me parece que haja qualquer impedimento semântico, pelo menos. E de facto encontram-se alguns exemplos na literatura, [por exemplo](https://books.google.nl/books?id=NBtHAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22me%20conv%C3%A9ns%22&hl=pt-PT&pg=PA251#v=onepage&q=convens&f=false) (grafia original):

> O sr. padre Manuel é um santo, mas sabe menos do que toda a gente a respeito de... em fim, não me **convens** para moça e procura outra casa

Comment: Se tivéssemos combinado não teríamos conseguido responder mais ao mesmo tempo. O teu «convéns» não tem acento?

Comment: @Jacinto Não o texto é do séc. XIX.

Comment: Pensei nisso, e ia dizer que não tinha encontrado mais nenhum sinal, mas reparo agora no «em fim».

Comment: No exemplo que construíste, estás a tratar um hipermercado por tu?

Comment: @Jacinto Não... Que te faz ter essa ideia? Estou simplesmente a dizer: se podemos dizer que um supermercado nos convém (é conviente), por que não havemos de poder que dizer alguém (porventura, a pessoa com quem estámos a falar) nos convém.

Comment: É verdade que tu não tens lá aspas, mas eu imaginei uma pessoa a dizer aquilo a alguém. Não subentendi o *se podemos dizer que*.